# LocalTaskservice - Flow is not proceeding after its marked complete

Tags: jbpm

I am using JBPM 5.4.0 and injecting created via spring container along with local task service. I register a LocalHTItemHandler in the session but even after marking my task as compelete (which happens without issues ) the flow doesn't proceed. What could be going wrong here?

Do I need to start a task server even with LocalTaskService?

Answer (score 1):

Have you called connect() on the task handler?  The handler only registers the session as a listener in a lazy way (which means when it needs to create the first task for the session), but if you complete a task first, the engine might not be listening yet.  Calling connect() on the handler would register the listener immediately.

Kris

Comment: Yes, I did. Its callled as part of spring bean initialization.

Comment: humanTaskHandler= new LocalHTWorkItemHandler(taskService,ksession);
  humanTaskHandler.setLocal(true);
  humanTaskHandler.setIpAddress("127.0.0.1");
  humanTaskHandler.setPort(9123);
  ksession.getWorkItemManager().registerWorkItemHandler("Human Task", humanTaskHandler);
  ksession.startProcess("com.sample.bpmn");
  System.out.println("WorkflowInitializer:: Task Handler Initialised ::::");
  humanTaskHandler.connect();
  System.out.println(humanTaskHandler.isConnected());

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to format my code above. But essentially, I use LocalHTWorkItemHandler and register it with the session. This happens as part of spring initization, then I use Taskservice to mark my tasks complete.  The task completion requests comes much after the flow has been initialized.

Comment: Are you reusing the same session and taskService for all requests?  It might be useful to debug the application (or add some sysout statements in the handler) to check if the LocalHTWorkItemHandler is successfully triggered when the task is completed.

Comment: Yes, I am using same session and taskService for all requests. Should they be different? I see that code flows up fireTaskCompleted but nothing happens after that. Any suggestions where I should check for LocalHTWorkItemHandler trigger?

Comment: I did more debugging and could see that it calls *handleEvent* method of *MessagingTaskEventListener*  but when it tries to get the targets it always get null. Is there something I need to do to ensure that targets are not returned null?